# Ruby on Mac OSX via Mac Ports

Tags: ruby, macos, macports

I'm new to both Ruby and to Mac OSX, though I do have a fair amount of experience with Unix commands. I just installed Ruby 1.9 via a MacPorts command (port install ruby19). I then needed to do a find from root just to figure out where it went, which turned out to be: /opt/local/var/macports/software/ruby19/1.9.1-p376_0/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9.

The current version of Ruby (1.8.6) runs via /usr/bin/ruby, which is a symbolic link to /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby where Current is a symbolic link to a directory called 1.8.

I'd like to make Ruby 1.9 my default (along with related tools like irb), and while I can manage to do that, I'd like to know if there's a conventional way. Should I copy or link the MacPorts path to /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.9 and then point Current to 1.9? (I'd also have rename or copy the executables: ruby1.9 to ruby, irb1.9 to irb, etc.) Or should I just blow away the /usr/bin/ruby link (and /usr/bin/irb, etc) and create new ones pointing to the MacPorts version?

Comment: You should *not* remove (or touch, frankly) the system's Ruby (or Perl or Python). Leave that exactly as it is. The system expects it to be there, and you have no way of knowing in advance how many (or which) things depend on it. In this case, `rvm` is an excellent tool to manage multiple Ruby interpreters, but there's *always* a better answer than "remove the default."

Comment: All the rvm suggestions are a good example of Straw Men.  Specifically, you want a system ruby, a ruby for anywhere.  You want /opt/local/bin/ruby to be ruby1.9. Now, unix provides the $PATH variable for this, /usr/bin/${ruby binaries} won't be looked for assuming you set up your path correctly, which you have it seems.  RVM is a great tool, unless you want to use ruby every day by default.

Comment: port install ruby19 +nosuffix, btw ;)

Comment: I want to be able to execute ruby 1.9 scripts from makefiles XCode executes.  RVM puts a **huge** amount of stuff in the environment variables.  Anyone know a way to install 1.9 and direct XCode to run it from the makefiles ??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My advice:

```
$ port uninstall ruby1.9
```

Then follow this: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Then:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2
$ rvm --default 1.9.2
```

You might even `rvm install macruby` to toy with Cocoa.

Comment: +1 here, and checkout homebrew for other package management http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Comment: Thanks! Rvm seems like a bit of a commitment, but probably worth the effort.

Comment: rvm has a bunch of options, but for starters, you can get by only with these three: `rvm install` to get a new ruby, `rvm use` to switch versions, and once in a while `rvm update` to get the new stuff. Everything else you can learn at your leisure, when you need it (e.g. multiversion testing).

Comment: While this solution works good, it does not answer the TS question - "how to .. with tool XXX? don't use XXX"

Answer (score 28):

You can easy to use port select command, under MacPorts 2.1.3

```
$sudo port select --set ruby ruby19
```

Comment: This is apparently the "proper" MacPorts way to do it now instead of `+nosuffix`

Answer (score 26):

Install the `nosuffix` variant instead:

```
sudo port install ruby19 +nosuffix
```

Your newer ruby version should now take precedence over the preinstalled one.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I didn't see that option.

Answer (score 19):

In the lastest version of macports (2.1.3 or greater) you can use the `port select` command.

```
port select --list ruby
sudo port select --set ruby ruby19
```

For earlier versions of macports you can make a symbolic link to the numbered ruby version.  This is the way that macports generally handles switching between different versions of packages.

```
cd /opt/local/bin
sudo ln -s ruby1.9 ruby
```

Answer (score 5):

I would *highly* recommend [RVM](https://rvm.io). It takes a bit of reading, but once you have it installed you can install a ruby with `rvm install 1.9` (or jruby, ree, 1.8, etc), and switch between them with `rvm 1.9`. Each ruby version will also have its own, completely isolated set of rubygems.

Answer (score 2):

The `ruby1.9` binary should be installed in `/opt/local/bin`; if it's not, you may not have activated the port.

The easiest way to make Ruby 1.9 the default root is to create an alias for `ruby` to `ruby1.9`. If you're using Bash, you can do that by putting this in your Bash config file:

```
alias ruby='/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I do have /opt/local/bin/ruby1.9. I'll probably enable it with a symbolic link rather than an alias, but either way would work.

Comment: That's not enough probably. You should link, gem, rdoc and a series of files that come with ruby1.9. The best solution to keep your system clean is using RVM. System's or even macports ruby can be used for compiling i.e. vim with ruby support.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall ruby version 1.8:
***sudo port uninstall ruby***
Install ruby version 1.9:
***sudo port install ruby19***
Reopen terminal

Comment: Not sure it's necessary to reopen terminal.