# How to install Ruby 1.9.2-p290 via macports

Tags: ruby, macports

I am trying to install Ruby 1.9.2-p290 via macports. I just installed the port 'ruby', and I ended up with ruby 1.8.7. Any idea how to install a specific version of ruby?

I've heard the use of rvm, however, I dont seem to have rvm on my mac. Would it be better than macports? If yes, why and how can I get it? Would it be possible to get it via macports?

Thanks!

Comment: Searching for "rvm" should have returned some information about how to get it. http://beginrescueend.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, ruby 1.8.7 is the stock ruby on OS X. If you install another Ruby version (with MacPorts for example) you will have to tell your OS to use it instead of the stock one. It can be very messy this way.

So I recommend hardly to use rvm. It will be better than Macports, because you will be able to install the Ruby version you want. You can even have multiple Ruby version and switch whenever you want.

Rvm is not installed by default on your Mac, but consider checking out this simple [guide](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) to get started.

Answer (score 4):

rvm may be an excellent answer if you're going to be working with ruby a lot, but that's not the actual answer for why MacPorts appears not to do the correct thing.

By default, the MacPorts `ruby` package installs the binary as `/opt/local/bin/ruby19`. If you run `which ruby19` that should confirm it was indeed installed by MacPorts correctly.

This is not [what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333569/how-does-macports-install-packages-how-can-i-activate-a-ruby-installation-done) [anybody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464285/ruby-on-mac-osx-via-mac-ports) [expects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489700/making-ruby-1-9-default-on-os-x) though, so it helps to know the poorly documented `select` command syntax. As of MacPorts v2.1.3, the proper way to make the MacPorts-installed ruby19 the "system default ruby" is: `sudo port select --set ruby ruby19`

*In older versions the "proper" way to make ruby19 the default was to install the `+nosuffix` variant (which no longer exists) like this: `sudo port install ruby +nosuffix`.*